# Do I need to rebuild my iOS8 Beta static library (or framework) after GA release?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, ios8

I created a static library that utilizes iOS8 feature and I build against the beta version. When the GA released and I could publish my app that is targeting iOS8 GA, do I need to rebuild the SDK for iOS8 GA or I will not have an issue in development (assuming the APIs are the same) or with Apple approval when publishing the App.